# Gradle Error: Build failed with an exception, a problem occured while configuring project ':Demo'

Tags: android, gradle

While adding a project as a module

**What went wrong:**
It is too late to modify excludes
It has already been read to configure the project.

Consider either moving this call to be during evaluation, are using the variant API.

**Steps followed:** File -> Import module -> selec project file

[Gradle Failed Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKp9A.jpg)

Comment: Please first try Invalidate Cache Restart, clean.

Comment: I got the same issue. First I update androidx.appcompat:appcompat to 1.5.1 as recommended. Caused error. Said update gradle. So I update to 7.3.1 and I get the error above. I get the error above if I DONT upgrade androidx.appcompat:appcompat from 1.41. when I update gradle. I dont even know what 'exclude' they are talking about!

Comment: That didnt work for me. Got the same error. What does it mean? What is the variant API? What call are they talking about? Who wrote that error message?

Answer (score 2):

My project uses [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) and this exception occurred.
Updating the version of [Protobuf Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) from `0.8.13` to `0.9.1` resolved the error.

```
buildscript {
    ext.versions = [
        protobuf : [
            plugin: "0.9.1",
        ],
    ]

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:$versions.protobuf.plugin"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hashido-san! It worked for me too. How did you ever discover that from the error message provided?

Comment: I could not read any information from the error message provided.
I happened to update the library to the latest version and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Well, I have avoiding upgrading to the latest gradle because of that error for almost a year now. Had no idea it was because of the protobufs. You got me by an long, high steeplechase barrier. (Another reason not to use protobufs.)